# Parsing CREATE TABLE sql with regex

Tags: c, regex, linux

I'm doing a simple language sql with regex, and i'm parsing the sentence **CREATE TABLE**, but does not work. I use this:

```
reti = regcomp(&regex,  "CREATE TABLE [a-zA-Z]\\((.*)\\)", REG_EXTENDED);
```

It's something simple, i just do it to learn...
What is wrong with the regex?

Comment: "Does not work" is not a useful problem description. Please provide sample input, and expected and actual output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apart from only working on *one* letter SQL tables, you are either omitting whitespaces before the open parentheses or, depending on the SQL and regex engine/string syntax, over-escaping your expression parentheses.

Check:

```
[A-Za-z]+\\s*
```

if it doesn't work and the plus sign is not recognized,

```
[A-Za-z][A-Za-z]*\\s*
```

and whether it's `\\\\(` or just `\\(` (it *should* be the latter. But better be sure).

This supports names such as `Antinoo` and `cUsToMeRs`, but not `Invoices_New` or `Suppliers2014`. You might want to add numbers and underscores to your regex. Since table names probably won't start with numbers, you'll want

```
[A-Z_a-z][A-Z_a-z0-9]*\\s*\\(([^;]*)\\)
```

Comment: Thanks for commeting. When i use "\(" or "\s", the compiler gives me an error: warning: unknown escape sequence: '\s' [enabled by default]. therefore i use double "\\"

Comment: My bad. You *did* say you were using C. So \\s is correct, and `\\(` should be too (I seem to remember some scenario where I needed `\\\\(` but I can no longer recall why and where. Just in case, checking is easy).